# Migrate User Define Types from Oracle to MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, oracle, database-migration

Can you help me to migrate the following lines from Oracle to MSSQL. Thank you.

```
create or replace TYPE "GPS_SEGMENT" is object (
  lat1 numeric (14,5),
  lon1 numeric (14,5),
  lat2 numeric (14,5),
  lon2 numeric (14,5)
  );

create or replace TYPE "GPS_SEGMENT_TABLE" is table of  gps_segment;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you'd want in SQL Server would be a User Defined Table Type:

```
CREATE TYPE udtGpsSegment AS TABLE
(
  lat1 numeric (14,5),
  lon1 numeric (14,5),
  lat2 numeric (14,5),
  lon2 numeric (14,5)
);
```

You could then use this as a table variable in MSSQL:

```
DECLARE @gpsSegment udtGpsSegment;
INSERT @gpsSegment(....)
```

Or take it as a parameter to a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE example (@gpsSegment udtGpsSegment READONLY)
AS
BEGIN
  -- note that you can't update/insert/delete udtGpsSegment, but you can select from it - if needed, select it into a temp table or table variable that can be updated/deleted/inserted.
END
```

Also note that this only works for SQL Server 2008R2+